# Google Sheets - Javascript move cursor right on edit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know there is no setting in Google Sheets to change the default cursor behavior to move the cursor RIGHT after an edit instead of DOWN.

In my application, this is important because the user is taking inventory fairly rapidly by scanning bar codes about the part such as Location, then the Part #, then the Quantity, then the lot #.

I am using a very simple three line program to get GoogleSheets to move the cursor right instead of down.

```
function onEdit(e) {
e.source.setActiveSelection(e.range.offset(0, 1));
}
```

Now technically, the cursor is still moved down, but then my code moves it back up and to the right one cell.

It takes about 1 second to move it. While this works, my challenge is if the user doing the scans enters the data before the code repositions the cursor, the data ends up in the wrong cell.

My question: Is there any way to get it to buffer the input until the onedit function completes?  If it would buffer the input, the data would always end up in the correct cell, even if the user enters the next data element before the function finished.

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range.offset(0, 1).activate();
}
```

[Range.activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate())

Comment: Can you explain your answer? Code-only answers without explanation tend to get downvoted or removed.

Answer (score 0):

The method provided by Cooper is more direct and fast:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range.offset(0, 1).activate();
}
```

There's no way to buffer the input or preventing the user to set the data before the script ends. Another thing to take into account is that if the user enters the data too fast it can skip some of the cells onEdit triggers. The most similar thing to a buffer memory in Apps Script is the properties service [1] which can help you to store data from previous runs.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tested it and don't notice a discernible improvement using Cooper's method. 

If there is no way to buffer the input until the script relocates the cell, I may not be able to convert this organization from Excel to Googlesheets. If only Sheets had a way to change the default cursor movement on Enter.